# Bash script help with echo and commands

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, gnome

What I'm trying to do is to make this script read a users input and them perform the command with the users input. I got echo working, but I can't get the rest to work after.

```
gnome-terminal -t 'Change User Password' \
    -x bash -c "echo 'What user needs their password change?' ; bash" \
    -x bash -c "read pswu ; bash" \
    -x bash -c "passwd $pswu ; bash"
```

Another question: I would like to know how to right-click a file and run a script with the filename without path or extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
gnome-terminal -t 'Change User Password' -x bash -c "echo 'What user needs their
 password change?' ; read pswu ; passwd \$pswu "
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to use the wrong tool for the job, mainly because `passwd` doesn't read form standard input but from the terminal (/dev/tty).

You probably need to use [`expect`](http://www.nist.gov/el/msid/expect.cfm) or one of its various workalikes.  This is designed to drive programs such as `passwd` which are interactive and expect terminal input (rather than standard input).

---

Looking at the triple-command being proposed, I do not see how the third `-x bash` is going to get the information from the second.  I'm not clear what the `bash`-inside-the-script is doing, either.  Surely, you would write a script which does the entire job, and then invoke the terminal to run that script.  Running three commands like that is very problematic, it seems to me.

Comment: +1 for "wrong tool for the job". There are tools specifically designed for this task, and expect is arguably the best.

Comment: I'm afraid Jonathan and Bryan misunderstood the question.